# Metric spaces showing function continuous

Tags: metric-spaces

Suppose $(X,P)$ is a metric space and $x_0$ is fixed point of $X$.

Define $f:X \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ ($x\in X$) by $x\mapsto P(x,x_0)$,
which means that $f(x)=P(x,x_0)=|x-x_0|$.

Show that f is continuous on $X$.

I know that for $f$ to be continuous on $X$, $f$ is continuous at each point of $X$.

---

This is what I did
Show $f$ is continuous on $X$

$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0$ such that $P(x,x_0)<\delta$ then
$P(f(x),f(x_0)<\epsilon=|x-x_0|+|x_0-x_0|$

But this show it is continuous on $x_0$ and I am a bit stuck.

Comment: $x,x_0\in X$, so how do you define $|x-x_0|$? In other words, what is subtraction? How do you have the triangle inequality? I think you should leave it as $P(x,x_0)$ and work with this instead.

Comment: I thought because the metric for R is $|x-x_0|$ maybe I am wrong I am begginer at metric spaces.

Comment: The standard metric in $\Bbb R$ *is* given by $|x-x_0|$ (where $x,x_0\in\Bbb R$), but how do you define absolute values for elements in $X$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Show that $|f(x) - f(y)| = |P(x_0,x) - P(x_0,y)| \le P(x,y)$ using the triangle inequality.

Comment: I am not sure how would you use triangle ineqaulity here is it

Comment: $|x+y|\le|x|+|y|$ then $||x-x_0|-|y-x_0|<|x-y|$

Comment: For any metric space we have a triangle inequality too. So for $P$ as well.

Comment: Oh I see so this is like the opposition of $P(x,y)<=P(x,x_0)+P(x_0,y)$

Comment: I think the reasoning is because the distance of the functions of metric space  are less than the distance of the point themselves then it is continous.

Comment: Better: $P(x,x_0) \le P(x, y) + P(y, x_0)$. Subtract $P(y, x_0)$. Same with $x,y$ interchanged. The max of these differences is the absolute value.